# Chromium TLS flags ignored when in headless mode

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, headless

I want to restrict Chromium to use up to TLSv1.2 protocol, according to [Chromium source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/common/content_switches.cc) we can force the TLS versions with some specific flags.

If I run Chromium normally with such flags like

```
./Chromium --ignore-certificate-errors --ssl-version-min=tls1 --ssl-version-max=tls1.2 --tlsv1 --tlsv1.1 --tlsv1.2 https://104.17.209.9
```

[image: Capture without headless mode]

I will end up seeing TLSv1.2 handshake as expected. If I run the same command but in headless mode, Chromium ends up using TLSv1.3.

```
./Chromium --headless --ignore-certificate-errors --ssl-version-min=tls1 --ssl-version-max=tls1.2 --tlsv1 --tlsv1.1 --tlsv1.2 https://104.17.209.9
```

[image: Capture with headless mode]

Why is this happening? Headless mode ignore/disable such flags?

Testing with Chromium 80.0.3987.0 on macOS Catalina 10.15.2 using the version coming with puppeteer 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1054891):

> The command-line flag is seen as part of our Enterprise configuration options, and I don't believe it's expected that Headless observes Enterprise flags (command-line or those set via Enterprise configuration stores, such as the Registry or Cloud Device Management)